# Problema con el responsive de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

El problema que tengo es que al hacerle responsive a la tabla esta se daña, no se porque pasa sabiendo que tiene un `width:"100%"` y tiene ambos `scroll`

Como esta inicialmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en el responsive:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se arregla cuando uno mueve algo pero quisiera que se arreglara, Como se debiera ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var table = $('#tblComprasRango').DataTable({
  scrollY:200,
  scrollX:true,
  scroller:{
    loadingIndicator: true
  },
  dom: 'frtipB',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<div class="comprasRango" class="tab-pane fade">
  <table id="tblComprasRango" class="table table-striped table-border table-condensed table-holver" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Boleta</th>
        <th>Total&nbsp;Compras</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>1</td>   
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>5</td>       
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>15</td>        
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>1</td>   
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>5</td>       
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>15</td>        
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar colocando la propiedad de DataTable responsive, ademas te recomendaria agregar la propiedad bDestroy si es que necesitas que la tabla se vuelva a leer:

```
bDestroy: true,
responsive: true,
```

si necesitas mas información, recuerda consultar la documentación oficial
[documentación oficial](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/)

Comment: Ya lo he leido y no me dice nada de como arreglarlo, intente con el destroy y tampoco funciona al igual con el responsive

Answer (score 0):

Esa no es la forma correcta de hacer un responsive, aqui te dejo la documentacion de como hacer datatables de forma responsive:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/

Y esto para darle estilos a tus botones de exportar

Datatables + bootstrap 4 + botones export + personalizacion

https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/gKqLEK

Y si por otro lado aun usas Bootstrap 3:

https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/XYOPEP